# How do I correct this string traveling method?

Tags: c++

My intention with this code is that the user types a string and a substring, then the 'esSubString' function finds if this substring is inside the main string. I think the main problem is the "while(j<lngSubStr && coincidencia)" part, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
#include "substring.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool esSubString(char str[], char subStr[], int& posicio)
{
    int lngSubStr = strlen(subStr);
    int lngStr = strlen(str);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    bool coincidencia = true;
    bool trobat = false;
    bool saltando = true;
    
    cout << lngSubStr << endl;
    cout << lngStr << endl;
    
    while (i < lngStr && !trobat)
    {
        posicio = i;
        coincidencia = true;
        
        while (j < lngSubStr && coincidencia)
        {
            j = 0;
            if (subStr[j] != str[i])
                coincidencia = false;
            else
                j++;
            i++;
        }
        
        saltando = true;
        while (saltando && i < lngStr)
        {
            if ((str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') || (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'))
                i++;
            else
                saltando = false;
        }
        
        if (coincidencia)
            trobat = true;
    }
        
    return trobat;
}
```

Comment: `std::string` has member function `find`, which will do this for you. See [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), which describes its operation: "Finds the first substring equal to the given character sequence."

Comment: You failed to tell us what the problem is. What is the symptom?

Comment: One bug (perhaps among other) is that `i` is the variable in charge of making the outer `while` loop progress, but you increase it inside the inner loop. When you exit the inner loop, if you have checked several characters, the outer loop won't resume where you want it to. It could have been fine: I see you have a line doing `posicio = i;`, which I believe was for the purpose of saving the progress of the outer loop. However, you never restore that saved value with a `i = posicio;`... In your code, a `for` would have made everything cleaner.

Comment: Looks like you are learning (or have learned) C++ from an outdated source. For strings use `std::string` or `std::string_view`. But please stop using this "C" style `char[]` code.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I correct this string traveling method? My intention with this code is that the user types a string and a substring, then the 'esSubString' function finds if this substring is inside the main string.

The outer loop of the program in the OP varies the starting subscript in parameter `str`. Variable `i` keeps track of this starting location. You want to search starting at subscript 0, and, if that fails, at subscript 1, and so on. So far, so good.

The inner loop is the problem. Variable `j`, which is an index into parameter `subStr`, should be reset to 0 outside the inner loop, rather than inside it. At the same time, a third variable, say `k` should be declared outside the inner loop, and set to the current value of `i`. Variable `k` will be a subscript into parameter `str`. It will be the variable that gets incremented in the inner loop along with variable `j`.

In the OP, you get into trouble, because you treat variable `i` the way you should be treating variable `k`. You increment `i` as you scan across parameter `str` in the inner loop. That is wrong. Variable `i` needs to be held constant in the inner loop, so that you do not lose track of where you are in the outer loop. Variable `k` is the one that should be incremented in the inner loop.

In addition to these problems, there is a secondary calculation involving variable `saltando`, and a test to see whether certain characters are letters. I could not figure out what was intended by this block. I am concerned, however, that it gets in the way of finding a substring, so I have omitted it in the following program.

The function below incorporates those changes, along with a few others that are detailed in the comments. This is the minimal amount of "patching" needed to get the function to work.

```cpp
bool esSubString(char str[], char subStr[], int& posicio)
{
    int lngSubStr = strlen(subStr);    // compiler warning: lossy conversion
    int lngStr = strlen(str);          // compiler warning: lossy conversion
    int i = 0;                         // subscripts should have type `std::size_t`
    int j = 0;                         // `j` could be declared in body of outer loop
    bool coincidencia = true;          // redundant, could uses `trobat` for this
    bool trobat = false;
    //bool saltando = true;            // `saltando` block removed from compilation

    cout << "lngSubStr: " << lngSubStr << endl;
    cout << "lngStr: " << lngStr << endl;

    while (i < lngStr && !trobat)
    {
        //posicio = i;                 // set `posicio` below, after a match
        coincidencia = true;

        j = 0;                         // reset `j` outside of inner loop
        std::size_t k{ static_cast<std::size_t>(i) };  // add `k`, an index into `str`
        while (j < lngSubStr && coincidencia)
        {
            //j = 0;                   // do not reset `j` inside inner loop!
            if (subStr[j] != str[k])   // replace `i` with `k`
                coincidencia = false;  // could also break out of inner loop
            //else                     // remove else
                j++;                   // this increment should not be conditional
            k++;                       // replace `i` with `k`
        }
#if 0                                  // `saltando` block removed from compilation
        saltando = true;
        while (saltando && i < lngStr)
        {
            if ((str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') || (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'))
                i++;
            else
                saltando = false;
        }
#endif
        if (coincidencia)
        {
            trobat = true;
            posicio = i;               // set `posicio` after a match
        }
        i++;                           // increment `i` here
                                       // not in `saltando` block
    }
    return trobat;
}
```

A better approach, modeled on function `find` from class `std::string`, is described in the sections that follow.

##### A solution using `std::string`

Member function `find`, from class `std::string`, does everything you need. It is [documented at CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find). With it, you can craft the following solution that preserves the interface of function `esSubString`.

```cpp
bool esSubString(char str[], char subStr[], int& posicio)
{
    std::size_t const pos{ std::string{ str }.find(subStr) };
    bool const trobat{ pos != std::string::npos };
    if (trobat)
        posicio = static_cast<int>(pos);
    return trobat;
}
```

##### Taking the lead from the Standard Library

Supposing that we must use C-strings, and cannot use `std::string`, we can still follow the example of the Standard Library. Function `std::equal` and member function `find`, from class `std::string` are the ones I want to mimic. I'll put my versions of those functions in namespace `tbx`.

Using them leads to the following solution, which preserves the interface of function `esSubString` given in the OP.

```cpp
bool esSubString(char str[], char subStr[], int& posicio)
{
    std::size_t const pos{ tbx::find(str, subStr) };
    bool const trobat{ pos != tbx::npos };
    if (trobat)
        posicio = static_cast<int>(pos);
    return trobat;
}
```

##### Function `equal` compares ranges, not C-strings

Function `tbx::equal` compares the characters in two half-open ranges, and returns `true` when the strings they represent are equal, and `false` otherwise.

By using function `tbx::equal`, it is possible to eliminate the inner loop in the OP.

```cpp
namespace tbx
{
    bool equal(
        char const* first,   // string 1: pointer to the first character
        char const* last,    // string 1: pointer to the character one beyond the last
        char const* first2)  // string 2: pointer to the first character
    {
        while (first != last)
            if (*first++ != *first2++)  // a familiar C idiom
                return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note that the "half-open" range denoted by `[first, last)` need not be a C-string. In particular, it might, or might not, be terminated with a null character (`'\0'`). Indeed, if we knew that `string 1` and `string 2` (above) were C-strings, we could compare them with `std::strcmp`. We would not need function `equal` at all!

In practice, `string 1` will be the parameter `search_for`, and will, in fact, be a C-string. What I called `string 2`, however, will be a range of characters taken from the middle of parameter `str`. It will not be a C-string.

Note, as well, that function `equal` is much simpler than the inner loop of the OP. A big part of the reason is because *it uses pointers, instead of subscripts.*

##### Function `find` follows the example of `std::string`

Since the interface is one that most C++ programmers are familiar with, it makes sense to mimic the interface of member function `find` from class `std::string`.

My version takes two C-strings as arguments. The first, parameter `str`, is the string to search. The second, parameter `search_for`, is the substring you are searching for. A third parameter supplies the subscript in parameter `str` where the search begins. It defaults to zero.

```cpp
namespace tbx
{
    std::size_t find(
        char const* str,
        char const* search_for,
        std::size_t const pos = {})  // begin search at subscript `pos`
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

When a substring is found, `find` returns the subscript where the match begins. When the search for a substring fails, `find` returns a sentinel value, `tbx::npos`, that means "no position" or "not found".

```cpp
namespace tbx
{
    std::size_t constexpr npos
    {
        // `npos` is a sentinel value, which means "no position."
        std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()
    };
}
```

The first few lines of function `find` check the lengths of the strings, to verify that there are enough characters in parameter `str` for a search to be successful. If parameter `search_for` is longer than parameter `str`, then the search fails, and `tbx::npos` is returned.

```cpp
auto const len_str{ std::strlen(str) };
auto const len_search_for{ std::strlen(search_for) };
if (len_search_for > len_str)
    return tbx::npos;
```

After that, variable `pos_max` is calculated. It is the last possible starting position for a search. For instance, when `str` and `search_for` have equal lengths, `pos_max` is `0`, because it wouldn't make sense to start a search at position `1` (or anyplace else). If you did, you would run out of characters in parameter `str`, before finding the last character of parameter `search_for`.

As another example, assume `str` has `10` characters, and `search_for`, only `3`. In that case, the last possible match would be `str[7]` through `str[9]`, and `pos_max` would be `7`.

```cpp
std::size_t const pos_max{ len_str - len_search_for };
```

The rest of function `find` is a straightforward loop that sets up the various starting positions, and calls function `equal` to do the comparisons. This is the `i` loop from the OP. Note how much simpler it is here.

```cpp
for (auto p{ pos }; p <= pos_max; ++p)
{
    if (tbx::equal(
        search_for,                     // first
        search_for + len_search_for,    // last
        str + p)                        // first2
        )
        return p;  // Return position where match was found.
}
return tbx::npos;  // Return `npos` when the search fails.
```

##### Complete program

Here is the complete program, along with a simple driver in function `main`.

As a bonus, I tossed in function `tbx::contains`, which returns `true` when its first parameter, `str`, contains its second parameter, `substring`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

namespace tbx
{
    bool equal(
        char const* first,   // string 1: pointer to the first character
        char const* last,    // string 1: pointer to the character one beyond the last
        char const* first2)  // string 2: pointer to the first character
    {
        while (first != last)
            if (*first++ != *first2++)
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    std::size_t constexpr npos
    {
        // `npos` is a sentinel value, which means "no position."
        std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()
    };

    std::size_t find(
        char const* str,
        char const* search_for,
        std::size_t const pos = {})  // begin search at subscript `pos`
    {
        auto const len_str{ std::strlen(str) };
        auto const len_search_for{ std::strlen(search_for) };
        if (len_search_for > len_str)
            return tbx::npos;
        std::size_t const pos_max{ len_str - len_search_for };
        for (auto p{ pos }; p <= pos_max; ++p)
        {
            if (tbx::equal(
                search_for,                     // first
                search_for + len_search_for,    // last
                str + p)                        // first2
                )
                return p;  // Return position where match was found.
        }
        return tbx::npos;  // Return `npos` when the search fails.
    }

    bool contains(char const* str, char const* substring)
    {
        return tbx::find(str, substring) != tbx::npos;
    }
}

bool esSubString(char str[], char subStr[], int& posicio)
{
    std::size_t const pos{ tbx::find(str, subStr) };
    bool const trobat{ pos != tbx::npos };
    if (trobat)
        posicio = static_cast<int>(pos);
    return trobat;
}

bool esSubString2(char str[], char subStr[], int& posicio)
{
    std::size_t const pos{ std::string{ str }.find(subStr) };
    bool const trobat{ pos != std::string::npos };
    if (trobat)
        posicio = static_cast<int>(pos);
    return trobat;
}

using std::cout;  // OP has `using namespace std;`
using std::endl;  // These using declarations obviate the need for that.

bool esSubString3(char str[], char subStr[], int& posicio)
{
    int lngSubStr = strlen(subStr);    // compiler warning: lossy conversion
    int lngStr = strlen(str);          // compiler warning: lossy conversion
    int i = 0;                         // subscripts should have type `std::size_t`
    int j = 0;                         // `j` could be declared in body of outer loop
    bool coincidencia = true;          // redundant, could uses `trobat` for this
    bool trobat = false;
    //bool saltando = true;            // `saltando` block removed from compilation

    cout << "lngSubStr: " << lngSubStr << endl;
    cout << "lngStr: " << lngStr << endl;

    while (i < lngStr && !trobat)
    {
        //posicio = i;                 // set `posicio` below, after a match
        coincidencia = true;

        j = 0;                         // reset `j` outside of inner loop
        std::size_t k{ static_cast<std::size_t>(i) };  // add `k`, an index into `str`
        while (j < lngSubStr && coincidencia)
        {
            //j = 0;                   // do not reset `j` inside inner loop!
            if (subStr[j] != str[k])   // replace `i` with `k`
                coincidencia = false;  // could also break out of inner loop
            //else                     // remove else
                j++;                   // this increment should not be conditional
            k++;                       // replace `i` with `k`
        }
#if 0                                  // `saltando` block removed from compilation
        saltando = true;
        while (saltando && i < lngStr)
        {
            if ((str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') || (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'))
                i++;
            else
                saltando = false;
        }
#endif
        if (coincidencia)
        {
            trobat = true;
            posicio = i;               // set `posicio` after a match
        }
        i++;                           // increment `i` here
                                       // not in `saltando` block
    }
    return trobat;
}

void test(char const* str, char const* substring)
{
    bool const is_substr{ tbx::contains(str, substring) };
    std::size_t const found_at{ tbx::find(str, substring) };
    int posicio{};
    bool const trobat = esSubString(
        const_cast<char*>(str),
        const_cast<char*>(substring),
        posicio);
    assert(trobat == is_substr);
    if (trobat)
        assert(posicio == static_cast<int>(found_at));
    int posicio2{};
    bool const trobat2 = esSubString2(
        const_cast<char*>(str),
        const_cast<char*>(substring),
        posicio2);
    assert(trobat2 == is_substr);
    if (trobat2)
        assert(posicio2 == static_cast<int>(found_at));
    int posicio3{};
    bool const trobat3 = esSubString3(
        const_cast<char*>(str),
        const_cast<char*>(substring),
        posicio3);
    assert(trobat3 == is_substr);
    if (trobat3)
        assert(posicio3 == static_cast<int>(found_at));
    std::cout
        << std::boolalpha
        << std::quoted(str)
        << (is_substr ? " contains " : " does NOT contain ")
        << std::quoted(substring)
        << ".\n";
    if (is_substr)
        std::cout << "It was found at position " << found_at << ".\n";
    std::cout << "Here is a list of all the positions where "
        "the letter `o` appears: ";
    std::size_t p{};
    while ((p = tbx::find(str, "o", p)) != tbx::npos)
        std::cout << p++ << "  ";
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    test("Hello, World!", "World");
    test("Hello, World!", "!");
    test("Sometimes it don't always work!", "does not");
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

##### Output

Testing revealed a few weaknesses in the interface of function `esSubString`.

- As there is no plan to modify them, parameters `str` and `subStr` should probably use type `char const[]` (or `char const*`). That has the benefit of making them compatible with string literals.
- Parameter `posicio`, and all indexing variables, should use type `std::size_t`.

In function `test` (above), you can see the `const_cast` and `static_cast` that were used to work around these issues.

That is all it took, however, to generate the following output.

```
"Hello, World!" contains "World".
It was found at position 7.
Here is a list of all the positions where the letter `o` appears: 4  8

"Hello, World!" contains "!".
It was found at position 12.
Here is a list of all the positions where the letter `o` appears: 4  8

"Sometimes it don't always work!" does NOT contain "does not".
Here is a list of all the positions where the letter `o` appears: 1  14  27
```

##### Not surprising to everyone

I saved what might be a surprise for last. Function `tbx::equal` is not needed. The call to function `tbx::equal` can be replaced by a call to `std::equal`.

All that is neccesary is to change `tbx` to `std`. Leave everything else the same. Unless, that is, you want to delete function `tbx::equal` entirely!

Armed with this knowledge, and using the best bits from `tbx::find`, we can revisit function `esSubString`. The version below uses the recommended parameter types from the Output section above, and manages to squeeze the solution down to just 14 lines.

```cpp
bool esSubString(char const* str, char const* subStr, std::size_t& posicio)
{
    std::size_t lngSubStr{ std::strlen(subStr) };
    std::size_t lngStr{ std::strlen(str) };
    if (lngSubStr > lngStr)
        return false;
    std::size_t const pos_max{ lngStr - lngSubStr };
    for (std::size_t p{}; p <= pos_max; ++p)
        if (std::equal(subStr, subStr + lngSubStr, str + p)) {
            posicio = p;
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Nevertheless, it is my opinion that the interface of `tbx::find`, which will be familiar to many C++ programmers, is the superior design. Both, however, take a back seat to using member function `find` from `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you reinitialize `j=0` at each step of the `while`. You will need to initialize it before the `while`, like:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool esSubString(string str, string subStr, int& posicio)
{
    int lngSubStr=subStr.size();
    int lngStr=str.size();
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    bool coincidencia=true;
    bool trobat=false;
    bool saltando=true;
    
    while(i<lngStr && !trobat)
    {
        coincidencia=true;
        int srch = i;
        j=0;
        
        while(j<lngSubStr && srch < lngStr && coincidencia)
        {
            if (i == 2) cout << subStr[j] << " " << str[srch] << endl;
            if(subStr[j]!=str[srch])
                coincidencia=false;
            else
                j++;
            srch++;
        }
        
        /*saltando=true;
        while(saltando && i<lngStr)
        {
            if((str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') || (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'))
                i++;
            else
                saltando=false;
        }*/
        
        if(coincidencia) {
            trobat=true;
            posicio = i;
        }

        i++;
    }
        
    return trobat;
    
}
int main() {
    int posicio = -1;
    esSubString("abcde", "cd", posicio);
    std::cout << posicio << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I commented out a part of your function to test only what you asked about. Feel free to uncomment it.

Comment: You're passing C strings to `esSubString` in `main` which are not null-terminated. `esSubString` immediately passes these to `strlen`. Undefined behavior ensues.

Comment: There's also an opportunity to eliminate extraneous newlines.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer to use string objects instead.